# Vacuum manifold and moduli space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, vacuum, symmetry-breaking, moduli

Vacuum manifold is just another name for the manifold spanned by the ground states of quantum field theory. It is also called moduli space.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_manifold, they said:

> Vacuum manifolds arise during the process of spontaneous symmetry
> breaking from a group $G$ to a subgroup $H$ and the corresponding
> vacuum manifold has to be a realization of G and contain the quotient
> space $G/H$. In many cases, it would simply be $G/H$, although it
> could be larger.

**Question:** In which cases, the vacuum manifolds or moduli space can be larger than $G/H$? Are there good canonical expected examples or surprising examples?

Comment: I edited and only post a question - please reopen :)